# Inserting an element in a multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

The shape of `B` is `(1,7,1)`. I am trying to insert `B1` at a specific position in `B` but how do I keep the shape of new array `B2` same as `B` with an extra element i.e. `(1,8,1)`? The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np
B = np.array([[[0.678731133],
        [1.244425627],
        [0.767884084],
        [2.006154222],
        [3.073758392],
        [1.037728999],
        [5.032947535]]])
B1=np.array([[10]])
B2=np.insert(B, 2, B1)
print("B2=",[B2])
print("B2 shape=",[B2.shape])
```

The current output is

```
B2= [array([ 0.678731133,  1.244425627, 10.000000000,  0.767884084,
        2.006154222,  3.073758392,  1.037728999,  5.032947535])]
B2 shape= [(8,)]
```

The desired output is

```
B2=np.array([[[0.678731133],
        [1.244425627],
        [0.767884084],
        [2.006154222],
        [3.073758392],
        [1.037728999],
        [5.032947535]]])

B2 shape=[(1, 8, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) say: `If axis is None then arr is flattened first`, which explains the result you are seeing. Try telling it which axis to insert into : `B2=np.insert(B, 2, B1, axis=1)`.

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([[[0.678731133],
        [1.244425627],
        [0.767884084],
        [2.006154222],
        [3.073758392],
        [1.037728999],
        [5.032947535]]])

B1=np.array([[10]])
B2=np.insert(B, 2, B1, axis=1)

print("B2=",B2)
print("B2 shape=",B2.shape)
```

This prints:

```
B2= [[[ 0.67873113]
  [ 1.24442563]
  [10.        ]
  [ 0.76788408]
  [ 2.00615422]
  [ 3.07375839]
  [ 1.037729  ]
  [ 5.03294753]]]
B2 shape= (1, 8, 1)
```

[Also, your desired output does not show the inserted element. I assume that's an oversight]